# Use JMSListener with RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, jms, spring-jms

My Application currently uses IBM MQ and has queue config setup and working fine with JMS. e.g.

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class IBMQueueConfig {

    @Bean("defaultContainer")
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                        final ErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

I can receive message and process as follows:

```
@Service
public class ProcessMessageReceive {

    @JmsListener(destination = "${queue}", concurrency = "${threads}", containerFactory = "defaultContainer")
    public Message processMessage(@Payload final String message) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

I need to use `RabbitMQ` for testing and require additional configuration.  I have the following the class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.rabbitmq")
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitMQConfiguration {

    private String host;
    private int port;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String virtualHost;


    @Bean
    public DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(exchange);
    }


    @Bean("defaultContainer")
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory(@Qualifier("rabbit-connection-factory") final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(); //ERROR
        return factory;
    }


    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(@Qualifier("rabbit-connection-factory") final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                               @Value("spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.concurrency") final int concurrency,
                                                                               @Value("spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.max-concurrency") final int maxConcurrency) {
        final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        containerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        containerFactory.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrency);
        containerFactory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConcurrency);
        containerFactory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);

        return containerFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "rabbit-connection-factory")
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        final CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost(host);
        connectionFactory.setPort(port);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(username);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue inboundQueue() {
        return new Queue(fixInboundQueue, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding inboundQueueBinding() {
        return bind(inboundQueue())
                .to(exchange())
                .with(routingKey);
    }
}
```

I get an error on line `factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);` as it expects a `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` but provided is Rabbit MQ One.

Is there a way I can wire in the Rabbit MQ ConnectionFactory ? I know it is possible if I use [`RMQConnectionFactory`](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-jms-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rabbitmq/jms/admin/RMQConnectionFactory.java), but I am looking to see If I can achieve it with Spring Rabbit dependency.

The objective is to avoid writing another `processMessage()` specifically for the Rabbit MQ and re-use what I already have.

Alternatively, can I use both annotations? In which case I would use spring profile to enable the one I need depending on prod or test?

```
  @RabbitListener(queues = "${app.rabbitmq.queue}") 
  @JmsListener(destination = "${queue}", concurrency = "${threads}", containerFactory = "defaultContainer")
    public Message processMessage(@Payload final String message) {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `@RabbitListener` instead of `@JmsListener` if you want to talk to RabbitMQ over AMQP.

You can add both annotations if you want to use JMS in production and RabbitMQ in tests.

Comment: do you mean on the same method have `@RabbitListener` && `@JmsListener` ? I could use profiles to activate the one I need?

Comment: Yes; l meant annotate the same method with both annotations; as long as you don't have spring-rabbit on the production class path, it will be ignored. However, let's say that in production you want to consume from JMS and produce to Rabbit, then you would need to set `autoStartup=false` on the rabbit container factory (or on the `@RabbitListener` itself) and `start()` it in your test case. That way, you can have rabbit on the class path but disable the listener. Or, yes, you could use profiles instead.

Comment: As the method is also annotated with `@JmsListener(destination = "${queue}", concurrency = "${concurrency}", containerFactory = "defaultContainer")` it looks for the `defaultContainer` bean and fails with `A component required a bean named 'defaultContainer' that could not be found.` class level profile applied, with local and prod. prod profile activates the defaultContainer which in this case was eliminated as I am launching app with `local `

Comment: You either need to remove spring-jms from the test class path or configure a dummy JMS container factory with `autoStartup` set to false.